# How can I hide labels in my chart?

Tags: morris.js

I've read the doc and its required, but I don't want it :D tried setting it to undefined and removing it but then javascript complains its misssing.

Is there a way to hide it?

Answer (score 2):

You can disable it through next option:

```
Morris.Line({
  hideHover: "always"
});
```

See [JsFiidle](http://jsfiddle.net/SergioV/czfzz2w4/)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a way through the configuration options, however you can easily hide it with css. 'display' is set by the script, but you can set the transparency:

```
.morris-hover {  
  opacity: 0;
}
```

seems to work fine for me here:
http://jsbin.com/aTirOKU/1/edit